# Could files downloaded from Youtube and Tumblr harm Mac?

Tags: video, data-transfer

I'm putting old files to fresh Mac and on one external drive, there is bunch of video files I downloaded from Youtube and Tumblr at one point few months ago.

Would it be safe to put them to fresh Mac or could those files be harmful? There didn't seem to be anything bad with them before, but as this is fresh Mac I'm more careful now.

Should I keep them away from fresh Mac just in case?

Comment: "downloaded from YouTube"? You can't download anything from YouTube—you can however use an outside YouTube-to-MP3 converter, which could lace the downloaded files with any malware it wanted to. So it depends!

Comment: @owlswipe Hello! I used this, before heard it is kind of illegal and stopped. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/download-youtube/ Only danger for youtube and tumblr files to be infected would stem from downloader then? The video files in Youtube and Tumblr server can't be infected?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well there are two points to this.

A.) there is a question of whether or not the files themselves contain any malicious code, which is hypothetically possible, but not likely. Owlswipe's comment is not correct in saying you cannot download files from YouTube, you can do so both through YouTube Red, as well as downloader extensions (which by the way are not illegal).

All a YouTube downloader extension does is use a program (often times wget, or something similar) to make a copy of the video file that is referenced in the html for that video's page. While it is possible for a downloader extension to infect that video file, it is quite unlikely for it to happen in practice. As far as files from Tumblr go you can probably safely assume the majority of posters on Tumblr do not have the knowledge how, or a reason to inject malware into a picture they are posting. Also seeing as both of these sites use HTTPS (Secure HyperText Transfer Protocol) it would not be possible for someone else to slip malware into either the file as you were downloading it or the page when you were connecting. Though there is always technically the possibility that their severs could be hijacked, it is very unlikely that it happened during the specific time you were downloading files. Which brings me to the second point.

B.) Macs run macOS, which is built on Unix. Unix is very secure, and generally hard to infect with malware. While this does not mean you should stop caring about keeping your computer safe (because it is still possible for a Mac to get infected), as long as you don't enter your password into random prompts saying a program you didn't launch wants to modify your system you should be fine. Typically it is only Windows that is vulnerable to the type of attacks used by malware that is contained in an image or video file, and it is because of the way Windows handles both security access and multimedia with a connected system.

All in all your Mac should be fine if you move your older files to it. Unless you know for sure that someone had hijacked the YouTube or Tumblr servers on the day you downloaded the files, you don't realistically need to worry about it getting infected by them. With that said always be careful when running programs you download from the internet, even on a Mac, as it is easier for malware in a program to infect any system than it is for malware in a video or image file.

Comment: This isn't correct, in multiple ways! Downloaded YouTube videos can't be copied to your disk as files (MP4 or otherwise) as per https://www.macxdvd.com/youtube-download-video/download-youtube-red-to-mp4.htm. *And*, Extensions used to download YouTube videos are illegal because they violate the YouTube terms of service, which state "You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content.You shall not copy...or otherwise exploit any Content for any other purposes without the prior written consent of YouTube."

Comment: And even hinting that a Mac is less vulnerable than a PC to malware is a bad idea. Exploits that get around GateKeeper (https://arstechnica.com/security/2015/09/drop-dead-simple-exploit-completely-bypasses-macs-malware-gatekeeper/) show up nearly all the time and being on an out of date version of macOS could make you vulnerable to numerous of these. So watch out what you suggest here!

Comment: -1 for the false information, though you do make a good point about HTTPS. Let me know if you edit your answer and I would consider changing to an upvote.

Comment: @owlswipe A.) Violating a website's terms of service is not inherently illegal, in this case it simply means they have the right to revoke your access to their service, as YouTube (and by extension Google) do not hold the copyright to the content being downloaded, the uploader does, and Google does not hold the legal authority to enforce said copyright on behalf of the holder without the holder's explicit request and verifiable statement that Google is to act as their representative on the matter. They have a right to terminate your account/ block your IP address, it is not however illegal.

Comment: @owlswipe B.) With that out of the way, the statement that *even hinting that a Mac is less vulnerable than a PC to malware is a bad idea.* only serves to demonstrate your ignorance on the topic. I would never claim that a Mac in invulnerable to malware, far from it. However, that doesn't change the fact however that *all* Unix and Unix-like systems from BSD to Linux are generally more secure than Windows due to fundamental low-level design differences. Also, an exploit that gets around GateKeeper does not directly open you up to a malware infection, it just means a program does not have to be

Comment: *continued* right-clicked in order to run if it is from an unsigned developer. A program being able to run does not magically provide it access to the root account, or somehow allow it to get around restrictions that prevent anyone other than the root account from even *reading* many files, and that is not even to mention that 10.11+ ship as *rootless* and require deliberate disabling of SIP from recovery mode to allow even the root account to modify system files. On top of all of that macOS runs on a hybrid kernel, meaning most software runs in user-mode, not kernel mode and all preinstalled

Comment: *continued* apps are sandboxed whenever possible, meaning an exploit in your browser, or your word processor is just that, an exploit in that app and only that app. Contrast that with Windows where almost everything from the desktop environment and stock browser are hooked directly into the kernel and an exploit in IE can be fairly easily used for privilege escalation to effect the system. Also, malware imbedded in a video is a Windows specific exploit irregardless of macOS security quality. Watch the CCC lecture on malware hidden in image files, they explain well why it only works in Windows.

Comment: A) Downloading those videos without express consent from YouTube or the creator of the video counts as "unauthorized reproduction" or [piracy](https://www.riaa.com/resources-learning/about-piracy/), which is a crime.

Comment: B) You are right that Macs get less malware than PCs, and thus are indeed significantly safer. But they are not invulnerable, and there *could* be a vulnerability/exploit being used in the wild that could circumvent the (many very good!) safeguards. I agree that it is unlikely to get malware from an MP4, but other things could be bundled along with that file that use social engineering to get users to open them or somehow get past macOS's formidable security, so you just sound a little too certain the OP is definitely safe with "you don't realistically need to worry about it getting infected".

Comment: I totally agree with you that the OP is probably safe, I just disagree with some of the points you made along the way (that this "legal" YouTube downloader couldn't have given the OP malware).

Comment: @owlswipe Once again Google does not own the copyright, YouTube does not have to express consent to prevent it from being piracy. So that begs the question: what if the creator has expressed that have no problem with a person downloading their content so long as it is not for monetary gain? Or alternatively if the creator of the content has not explicitly given permission, but knowingly chooses not to file any form of legal dispute because it is not being used for monetary gain? Free content, on a free platform, on which the host does not hold the copyright, but does have non-licensed right to

Comment: reproduce said content. When you enter in to a situation the DMCA never considered would exist you end up in a legal grey area. There are certainly some scenarios in which it would be piracy, say a person rents a Disney movie on YouTube and then downloads it, but there are other where it would not be, perhaps the creator expresses apathy or acceptance of their content being redisributed, and what of those with YouTube Red, who are provided a download button for almost anything? My point is not that it is perfectly legal, but that it cannot be blanketly claimed to be either legal or illegal.

Comment: @owlswipe I respect your disagreement, though that type of scenario is why I stated *as long as you don't enter your password into random prompts saying a program you didn't launch wants to modify your system you should be fine.*, I was not attempting to imply that the OP was safe from all methods of malware infection, there have certainly been cases like *Mac Defender*. Which is why I also included *With that said always be careful when running programs you download from the internet, even on a Mac*, as I meant to imply that videos specifically should be fine, rather than files in general.

Comment: OK, I think we mostly agree :D. Legality, I hope you'll admit, as at least questionable with these YouTube downloaders.

Comment: @owlswipe Oh, I agree that they're certainly legally grey at best and outright sketchy at worst in almost every situation, I just wanted to make sure the verdict was left to a case-by-case basis for the sake of fairness, that's of course not to say most cases wouldn't still be considered at least some form of copyright infringement, I just like to account for outliers as well :3